# Possibility of retrieving X value after Bitwise OR operator

Tags: logic

### *Z = X ∨ Y*

(where ***X, Y, Z*** are **96bits** binary numbers)

If I have ***"Z"*** value and ***"Y"*** value. Are there any possibilities to retrieve ***"X"*** value from ***"Z"***?

What I know is it is possible to do this with XOR operator, but is it same with OR operator?

Comment: Given: `X = 00; y = 11;  z = 11`. `X = 10; y = 01; Z = 11`.  `X = 10; y = 11; Z = 11`. If I told you `Z = 11` and `X = 10`. All you can say is `Y = ?1`

Comment: @MichaelT X, Y, Z are 96 bits binary numbers. NOT two bits.
Ex:

Z = 001100010001010000100101011110111111010101110100010110000101011000101010000000000000000000000000

Comment: So? The same applies for 1, 2, 96, or 12345 bits. Truth tables for bit wise operators work bit by bit.

Comment: @MichaelT I do not think it is same:
Z = 
011111001101101010010111111111011111111111111011011011010111101110111101000000111110011010101110

Y = 011011000101001010010101111010011101010111010001011000010101100010101000000000111100000000001010

Now can you get **X** which is equal to :
010110001000101000010010101111011111101010111010001011000010101100010101000000000110011010100100

From **Z** and **Y** ??

Comment: X could've started with 0001 or 0111 instead.  I have no way to prove that X started with 0101.

Comment: @MaulingMonkey In this case it is not possible to get the exact value of **X** isn't it??

Answer (score 3):

Each bit in the result is the result of an operation on the corresponding bits in the two operands.

For XOR:

```
X ^ Y = Z                 Y ^ Z = X 
0 ^ 0 = 0                 0 ^ 0 = 0 
0 ^ 1 = 1   --inverse->   1 ^ 1 = 0 
1 ^ 0 = 1                 0 ^ 1 = 1 
1 ^ 1 = 0                 1 ^ 0 = 1
```

Given a pair of bits from Y and Z, you can determine the value of that X's bit must've had.

For inclusive OR:

```
X | Y = Z                 Y ¤ Z = X
0 | 0 = 0                 0 ¤ 0 = 0
0 | 1 = 1   --inverse->   1 ¤ 1 = 0
1 | 0 = 1                 0 ¤ 1 = 1
1 | 1 = 1                 1 ¤ 1 = 1
```

We can see here that for the case of Y=1 Z=1, X could be either 0 and 1.
For the two other cases, you can determine the value of X.

The answer is that some of the bits of X can be reconstituted, but for any of the indeterminate cases, you will end up with indeterminate values.